# Call a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql

I trying to make a editable profile to users. They click on Edit button(form-post)That return the page with the editable information (only if isset($_POST["edit"]) in text areas, inputs and "complete editing" button. 
when i click complete editing. its need to start a function of update the new information to the database. but it`s not update its return a error of:

```
Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object
```

My code:

```
if(isset($_POST["cedit"]) && !empty($_POST["fn"]) && !empty($_POST["ln"]) && !empty($_POST["desc"])){

    if($stmtq = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `sites`.`accounts` SET `fullname` = ? ,`description` = ? WHERE `id` = ? ") && !empty($_POST["fn"]) && !empty($_POST["ln"]) && !empty($_POST["desc"])){
        $stmtq->bind_param("ssd", $_POST["fn"]." ".$_POST["ln"], $_POST["desc"], $_SESSION["user_id"]);
        $stmtq->execute();
        $stmtq->close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do `print_r($stmtq);` just after `prepare()`. Also check error log and add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` as very first thing in your script

Comment: Marcin the print_r($stmtq) returns number 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a problem with operator precedence causing `$stmtq` to be a `true` or `false` boolean instead of the prepared statement it's intended to be.

This is due to the chain of `&&` conditions packed into the same conditional. They happen before the assignment `=`. Add some `()`.  Basically it amounts to:

```
// $x is always assigned a boolean
if ($x = (object && true && true))
```

Instead of the intended

```
// $x is assigned the object
if (($x = object) && (true && true))
```

To fix it:

```
// Wrap the assignment in its own () group to isolate from the && conditions
if (($stmtq = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `sites`.`accounts` SET `fullname` = ? ,`description` = ? WHERE `id` = ? ")) && !empty($_POST["fn"]) && !empty($_POST["ln"]) && !empty($_POST["desc"]) {
  // Successful prepare() assignment and all other conditions
  // Proceed with bind_param()/execute()
}
```

Though it adds a couple of lines, it would be easier to read and less prone to these precedence problems to do the `prepare()` and assignment first, then validate the other conditions, or vice versa.

```
if (!empty($_POST["fn"]) && !empty($_POST["ln"]) && !empty($_POST["desc"])) {
  if ($stmtq = $mysqli->prepare(.....)) {
     // All is well, proceed with bind_param()/execute()
  }
}
```

For the delicious details, [here is PHP's operator precedence chart](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). The `&&` logical operator has a higher precedence than the `=` assignment.